# File session: is it always generated?

Tags: php, session

Does Php **always** create a session file as soon as `session_start()` is called, even though there's nothing to keep track of (= no variable written in `$_SESSION[]`)? If so, why?

Comment: For your first question, see the [documentation for `session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start).

Comment: I would only be assuming, but I would say yes. The file is created as a placeholder for future data to be written. Also, this is pretty easy to test.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I'm asking this because it's not just a "`session_start()`" call. If it were *that* simple I would not have asked it **`;)`**. It's not because you call `session_start()` and you see once the file created that you "guess" it will always be created. (See the way Apache Web server works (lot of things to learn before understanding it))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default PHP file-based sessions encode the session ID into the session file's filename. Since that's the only place the ID is kept normally, SOMETHING has to be kept to store the id. That means you'll get a file created, even if nothing is EVER written to `$_SESSION`.

In PHP-like pseudo code, basically this is occuring:

```
function session_start() {
     if (isset($_COOKIE[ini_get('session.name')])) {
           // session ID was sent from client, get it
           $id = $_COOKIE[ini_get('session.name')];
     } else {
           // no session ID received, generate one
           $id = generate_new_id();
           setcookie(ini_get('session.name'), $id, ......);
     }
     $session_file = ini_get('session.save_path') . '/sess_' . $id;
     if (file_exists($session_file)) {
        // found a session file, load it
        $raw_data = file_get_contents($session_file);
        $_SESSION = unserialize($raw_data);
     } else {
        // brand new session, create file and initialize empty session
        file_put_contents($session_file, serialize(array());
        $_SESSION = array();
     }
     // lock the session file to prevent parallel overwrites.
     flock($session_file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And you're right to precise that my question is about "PHP file-based sessions".

Comment: I'm trying to read manually and `unserialize()` like you wrote but it doesn't work (= return `false`).

Comment: a simple `cat` of the session file gives: `time|a:1:{s:7:"myboard";i:1394226330;}myboard|a:3:{s:2:"nb";i:1;s:5:"state";i:1;s:2:"id";s:34:"r9udjoolo9mkm0g2k010ob9fb5_myboard";}` so i guess i should be able to un-serialize it, right?

Comment: it's not quite pure serialized data. the `time|` business isn't valid serialize data. the rest, however, is.

Comment: So my other question is: is there a way to read and unserialize the session file?

Comment: there's `session_decode($raw_data_from_session_file)`, but as a side effect it'll decode into $_SESSION, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Ok I did this hack to read someone else's session: `session_write_close();` `session_id($someone_else_session_id);` `session_start();` `$session_someone_else=$_SESSION;` `session_write_close();` `session_id($session_id_sav);` `session_start();`

Comment: probably easier to just to `$temp = $_SESSION; $_SESSION=array(); session_decode(...); $decoded = $_SESSION; $_SESSION = $temp;`. saves you have to close your original session.

Comment: Ok! Faster-better like this now: `$session_someone_else=session_decode(file_get_contents($someone_else_session_filename));` Thank you very much for your advices